# Python built-in __del__ causing strange issues

Tags: python

I was learning about other built-in class methods in Python and came across one called `__del__()`. Like `__repr__()` and `__str__()`, I believed it could be overriden and decided to test it.

Here is a basic class I created:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __del__(self):
        print("Deleted!")
```

Just to confirm this code works, here is me testing it in the console:

```
>>> test = SomeClass()
>>> del test
Deleted!
```

When running in the console, I tested it with x and y variables:

```
>>> x = SomeClass()
>>> y = x
>>> del x # This should print "Deleted!"
>>> del y
Deleted!
```

Strangely, when deleting `x`, it never outputted anything, but when deleting `y`, which was assigned to be equal to the `x object`, it outputted "Deleted!".

I didn't stop there, though. I tested this concept again, but now with `a` and `b` variables.

```
>>> a = SomeClass()
>>> b = a
>>> del a
>>> b # Check if b exists
<__main__.SomeClass instance at 0x7f98a1a67fc8>
>>> del b # Like previously, with 'y', this should print "Deleted!"
>>> globals() # Well, it didn't. Let's check all our global variables to confirm
Deleted!
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'SomeClass': <class __main__.SomeClass at 0x7f98a1a5f668>, '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

As you can see, calling the humble `globals()` method seem to print "Deleted!" then printing the globals which contains no reference of `b`, so it did delete it.

How comes overriding the `__del__` method causes odd issues? I thought of using the method to control what happens when certain objects in a game are deleted, but now it makes me less convinced, as odd bugs may occur when I duplicate objects and delete them.

Comment: `__del__` is not a `del` hook. `__del__` is a *finalizer*.

Comment: `__del__` is not called because you used `del`. It is called when the *last reference* is removed. You created **two** references, `x` and `y`, so only when *both* are removed again is your object deleted from memory.

Comment: Next, the Python interactive interpreter stores the most recently produced result in the [`_` built-in name](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers). You echoed `b`, so the object was shown as a result and referenced by `_` until you produced a different result by executing `globals()` (at which point `_` is rebound to point to the global namespace dictionary, and the reference to the `SomeClass()` instance is removed and that instance is deleted because the reference count is now 0.

Comment: It bears repeating: you are not *duplicating* objects, you are simply creating multiple references to the same object.